# Getting error Filtering ListView inside PagerAdapter instantiateItem()

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I am experimenting with ViewPager and an ORM (androrm).  I have it running showing all of the items inside the ListView but it fails when I try to filter.  The filter works properly because I have tested it inside another activity.  When I run the PagerActivity and implement the filter I get an error.  The logCat is below.  I don't know if this is even possible.  I am looking to solve this issue.  If you have any other questions or need more information I will update the question

**Working statement**

```
logAdapter1 = new LogAdapter(PagerActivity.this, 0, Log.all());
```

**Error statement, works in separate activity**

```
logAdapter1 = new LogAdapter(PagerActivity.this, 0, Log.logsByName("NAME0"));
```

**Working PagerActivity (opened from MainActivity)**

```
public class PagerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    LogAdapter logAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.viewPager);
        setContentView(mViewPager);
        logAdapter = new LogAdapter(PagerActivity.this, 0, Log.all());
        MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log crime = logAdapter.getItem(position);
                if (crime.getName() != null) {
                    setTitle(crime.getName());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        LogAdapter logAdapter1;
        TextView textView;
        ListView list;

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Log log = logAdapter.getItem(position);
            list = new ListView(PagerActivity.this);
            // logAdapter1 = new LogAdapter(PagerActivity.this, 0, Log.logsByName("NAME0"));  // This is what I am trying to filter
            logAdapter1 = new LogAdapter(PagerActivity.this, 0, Log.all()); // Working with all list items
            list.setAdapter(logAdapter1);

            textView = new TextView(PagerActivity.this);
            textView.setText(log.getName());

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(PagerActivity.this);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            list.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            layout.addView(textView);
            layout.addView(list);
            container.addView(layout);
            return layout;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return logAdapter.getCount();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class LogAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Log> {
    Context mContext;
    public static List<Log> mLogs;

    public LogAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Log> logs) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        mContext = context;
        mLogs = logs;
    }

    public void setLogs(List<Log> logs) {
        mLogs = logs;
    }

    public List<Log> getLogs() {
        return mLogs;
    }

    public void add(Log log) {
        mLogs.add(log);
    }

    public void remove(Log log) {
        LogAdapter.mLogs.remove(log);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mLogs.size();
    }

    public Log getItem(int position) {
        return mLogs.get(position);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LogRow view = (LogRow) convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = new LogRow(mContext);
        }
        Log log = getItem(position);
        view.setLog(log);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Log**

```
public class Log extends Model {
    protected CharField mName;

    public Log() {
        super(true);
        mName = new CharField();
    }

    /* -G&S- */
    public void setName(String name) {
        mName.set(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName.get();
    }

    /* -Saving & Setting id based on position- */
    public boolean save() {
        int id = Log.objects(context(), Log.class).all().count() + 1;
        return this.save(context(), id);
    }

    /* -Filters the data based on mName- */
    public static List<Log> logsByName(String name) {
        String query_string = formatNameForQuery(name);
        Filter filter = new Filter();
        filter.contains("mName", query_string);
        return Log.objects().filter(filter).toList();
    }

    private static String formatNameForQuery(String name) {
        name = "" + name;
        return name;
    }

    /* -Return all data items without any filter, orders based on saved position- */
    public static List<Log> all() {
        return Log.objects().all().toList();
    }

    public static QuerySet<Log> objects() {
        return Log.objects(context(), Log.class);
    }

    private static Context context() {
        return AppActivity.context();
    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
1581-1581/contractor.com.dudeee.eugene.testingandrormwithlist E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: contractor.com.dudeee.eugene.testingandrormwithlist, PID: 1581
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at contractor.com.dudeee.eugene.testingandrormwithlist.LogAdapter.getItem(LogAdapter.java:41) //At LogAdapter "return mLogs.get(position);"
at contractor.com.dudeee.eugene.testingandrormwithlist.PagerActivity$MyPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PagerActivity.java:54) //At PagerActivity "Log log = logAdapter.getItem(position);"
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1053)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragments were sharing the adapter and when it was created, it was causing the single instance of the adapter to fire different filters.  I solved it with FragmentStatePagerAdapter, and individual instances of the adapter(each filter) based on the page.

**Activity**

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private void viewPagerConnections() {
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            LogSecond log = logSecondAdapter.getItem(position);
            return LogThirdFragment.newInstance(log.getDB_twoName(), position, log.getDB_twoKey());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return logSecondAdapter.getCount();
        }
    });
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPageInt);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            LogSecond logThird = logSecondAdapter.getItem(position);
            toolbar.setTitle(logThird.getDB_twoName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    });
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class LogThirdFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public static final String EXTRA_ID = "eugene_testing";

    public static LogThirdFragment newInstance(String name, int page, int dbTwoKey) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_ID, name);
        args.putInt("page", page);
        args.putInt("dbTwoKey", dbTwoKey);
        LogThirdFragment fragment = new LogThirdFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    View v;
    public ListView listLogExpense;
    TextView noLogsTextView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_three_layout, container, false);
        listLogExpense = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.log_list);
        noLogsTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.no_logs);
        return v;
    }

    LogThirdAdapter mThirdAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mThirdAdapter = new LogThirdAdapter(getActivity(), 0, LogThird.logsByKey(getArguments().getInt("dbTwoKey")));
        listLogExpense.setAdapter(mThirdAdapter);
        updateList();
    }

    private void updateList() {
        if (mThirdAdapter.getLogs().size() == 0) {
            noLogsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            noLogsTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```